# Supremum/Infimum and min/max

Tags: limits, supremum-and-infimum

(Problem written verbatim)

Let A = [0,1] - {$\frac1n$|n $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$}. Find supremum, infimum, maximum, and minimum of A. Justify your answers.

I'm not really sure where to start. I tried about 4 different ways of doing this and I think the best idea is to have subset K = {k $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ | 0 $\le$ k $\le$ 1} and L = {$\frac1n$|n $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$}
and show that, for example, min(A) = min(K) - max(L) = -1

I'm also supposing that I have to treat L as a limit, correct?

Comment: The minimum of $A$ cannot be a number that is not in $A$.